# Is it possible to give AzureChatOpenAI 'rules' to follow?

Tags: openai-api, langchain, py-langchain, azure-openai, azure-ai

I am working on a 'chat bot' for a work project that will let me 'talk' with documents. Part of the project is being able to have the AI know when not to answer certain questions. Essentially, I want to protect PII due to HIPPA laws, so if a user asks about something they wouldn't have access to, the AI won't answer or will reply with "I can't answer that..". Something I looked at was ConstitutionalChain and ConstitutionalPrinciple and implementing ethics, but I'm unsure if I'm able to implement that with document retrieval. Anyone worked with this before or encountered a different way to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering will be supported eventually, thus you can use security filters to trim the results. See Security filters for trimming results - [Azure Cognitive Search | Microsoft Learn.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-security-trimming-for-azure-search)